# How to get in which floor user is locate?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, google-elevation-api

I need to location of floor where is user currently locating and I tried two ways

using CLLocation and location.floor?.level 
and google elevation API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start

but on the First case, I got nil 
and the second case I get the elevation which I got in the first case but I didn't floor.

so how to get floor ? thanks

Comment: Look at this link http://www.indooratlas.com/ Might be useful.

Comment: thanks, @Gagan_iOS but I already know about that but Client don't want to use this.

Comment: Hi @NiravHathi, Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding :

If floor information is not available for the current location, the value of this property is nil.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clfloor/1616759-level

Comment: thanks, @Arasuvel but any other ways to get the floor.? It will be very helpfull.